# openapi-validator sends html instead of json in response

Tags: typescript, express, express-openapi-validator

I am using an operation handler for requests.
In the oas scheme I defined create user as:

```
/users:
post:
  description: |
    creates a user
  operationId: createUser
  x-eov-operation-handler: controllers/user.controller
  tags:
    - Users
  requestBody:
    description: User to create
    required: true
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          properties:
            email:
              type: string
              description: The email of the user
              example: example@gmail.com
              pattern: ^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,5}$
            password:
              type: string
              description: The password of  the user
              example: password1234
              minLength: 8
              maxLength: 16
          required:
            - email
            - password
          additionalProperties: false
  responses:
    '201':
      description: User was created
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
    '400':
      description: Bad request
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            properties:
              code:
                description: Http status code
                type: number
                example: 400
              message:
                description: The message of the response
                type: string
                example: Bad request
            required:
              - code
              - message
            additionalProperties: false
```

... etc

and these are my validator settings:

```
const openApiValidator = OpenApiValidator.middleware({
  apiSpec,
  operationHandlers: path.join(__dirname)
})
```

but in the response when I try to create a user with wrong email pattern, for example: examplegmail.com, instead of getting something like: `{400,'Bad request'}`
I get a HTML page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Bad Request: request.body.email should match pattern &quot;^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,5}$&quot;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.POST-/users-application/json (C:\Users\mager\Desktop\netflix-api_\node_modules\express-openapi-validator\src\middlewares\openapi.request.validator.ts:175:35)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at RequestValidator.validate (C:\Users\mager\Desktop\netflix-api_\node_modules\express-openapi-validator\src\middlewares\openapi.request.validator.ts:76:37)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\mager\Desktop\netflix-api_\node_modules\express-openapi-validator\src\openapi.validator.ts:282:49<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\mager\Desktop\netflix-api_\node_modules\express-openapi-validator\src\openapi.validator.ts:188:20<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Can i change this behaviour or is this how it is supposed to be?

**Edit**: I also have an error handler defined after openApiValidator

```
app.use(openApiValidator);
app.use(errorHandler);

function errorHandler(err: any, req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({
    code: err.status,
    message: err.message,
  });
}
```

**Edit 2: I managed to fix it**
my error handler was missing the **next** parameter, I thought I could omit that one cuz I wasn't using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it my error handler was missing the next parameter, I thought I could omit that one cuz I wasn't using it.